# iOS WebServices Login App

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hi I used the code of this site: http://dipinkrishna.com/blog/2012/03/iphoneios-programming-login-screen-post-data-url-parses-json-response/5/
to create a simple web service login app.

The issue now is, that the example on the website it's for iOS 6.1 But I want it in an iOS 7 layout with storyboard and not xib files. 
So I copied this in my project renamed all classes and controller, fixed all warnings and errors, but now, if I started the simulator with the app I get this runtime error:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException (lldb)
```

this message is in the thread: `0x10213b866:  jae    0x10213b870               ; __pthread_kill + 20`

I'm new on app development and I hope you can help me.

Comment: What's the line in the debugger BEFORE the one you quote?

Comment: hm i hope this it what you mean: there are some line with this signs like this in it: `0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)`